# How to remove an item of embedded document in another embedded document of a document in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

My models:

```
class City(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    population = IntField()

class Privince(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    cities = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(City))

class State(Document):
    name = StringField()
    provinces = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Privince))
```

I can remove `Province` of a State whit this code:

```
State.objects(name="Alaska").update_one(pull__provinces={"name": "Juneau"})
```

but i don't know how to remove a city of a `province`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i find a very simple way ! :

```
state_obj = State.objects.get(name="Alaska")
province_obj = state_obj.provinces({"name": "Juneau"})
for city in province_obj.cities:
    if city.name == "Test_City" and city.population == 10000:
        province_obj.cities.remove(city)
```